# Is it possible to send array from twig to controller without using a form?

Tags: php, twig, symfony

In twig I recive a array of items, then after some action inside i need to return array(with same or diffrent values). **So is it possible to send a array like slug so controller can recive that ?**

**EDIT**: This question got lot of downvotes maybe because i wasn't be clear what i need. i only asked this question like **Theoretical** , i only want to know is it possible to do in this way. Im not asking any code solution(i didnt input any of mine cus only want to know if someone ever got in this situation, and how can i approach to solving this) just **Theoretical answer** .

Comment: that's what a [form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) is for

Comment: yeah, i know this could work with form, but i wanted to findout is there any other options

Comment: You should do your processing before you load a view and definitely not in a twig view itself. Unless I misunderstand the question; it is not very clear what you want to do, can you illustrate it with the relevant code you have so far?

Comment: not sure why do you downvote the question, is it wrong to ask questions ?

Comment: Your question gets downvoted because it doesn't show any kind of research and effort. Your only other valid option would be to use some kind of ajax logic, but I don't think that this is what you want.

Comment: Nop, i  was trying to find this similar question/answer here, but no one asked yet

Comment: What he meant is show what you tried so far. What code did you write trying to achieve this. That way we can form an answer more properly.

Comment: Why using forms ? Why using PHP ? Why using Symfony ? Whyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy ?

Comment: It's symfony project.

Comment: While it is not wrong to ask questions you should review the guidelines on how to do so.  Code fragments help to overcome the often significant language barriers.  I think you might be asking how to generate a url with multiple parameters but that is just a guess.  I would suggest taking the time to carefully read: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html and see if there is something similar to whatever problem it is that you are trying to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, If you submit the info that is.

```
$request->request
```

can be used to get all the data. I suggest dumping this variable to see what it contains on submit. after that use, and just loop through it to get the entries

```
$request->request->get("data-name");
```

Comment: hm, intersting,is this a correct why to use, or do i realy need to work with form? btw. tnx for replay

Comment: If you make custom input fields, i.e multi-select dropdowns it isn't needed to use a symfony form.

Answer (score 0):

You can not talk back in the php scope your are in during your twig template processing. But you can call a controller and pass value to it

Off course your controller will need to understand the parameters your passing

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Controller:persist', { 'value': myarray })) }}
```

My example will call a controller named : `Controller` and a function named `persistAction($value)` and will `render` the result returner by the controller this part is optional.

[Look this documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html)
it explain how to call or render a url/controller and pass parameters